# No se ha inicializado la propiedad ConnectionString

Tags: c#, sql-server

Hola buen día estoy programando en C# tengo un método que a continuación muestro, pero me lanza un error que dice

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll Additional information: No se ha inicializado la propiedad ConnectionString

Realmente no logro encontrar el error si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradecería mucho.

```
public static bool Conectar()
    {
        bool conectado = false;
        conexion = new SqlConnection(cadenaConexion);
        try
        {            
            conexion.Open();
            conectado = true;
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            errorconexion = ex.Message;
        }
        return conectado;
    }
```

Comment: Hola sería mejor que agregaras el contenido de su cadena de conexion

Comment: ¿Podrías poner qué pones exactamente como cadenaConexión? Ponlo con los datos cambiados por si tienes información sensible en ellos, pero quisiera verlo por si está erroneamente formateada.

Comment: public void inicializar()
    {
        cadenaConexion = "SERVER=127.0.10.31;DATABASE=Example;User id=admin; Password=123456;";
    }

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: No se ha inicializado la propiedad ConnectionString.

Comment: Por que tienes un metodo que inicializa una variable??? Y no la defines como propia de tu clase, servicio, etc etc???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo te recomendaria hacer lo siguiente :

En tu web config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBConnStr" connectionString="server=127.0.10.31;database=Example;UID=admin;PWD=123456" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Y tambien te recomendaria que utilizaras asi tu variable, más que un metodo como tal, definir una variable dentro de tu Clase, Servicio o lo que sea, voy a suponer que es un Servicio

```
namespace MiNameSpace
{
    public class IServiceTopStore : IIServiceTopStore
    {
        public static string Db = (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnStr"].ConnectionString);
        public static bool Conectar()
        {
            bool conectado = false;
            SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(Db);
            try
            {            
               conexion.Open();
               conectado = true;
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
               errorconexion = ex.Message;
            }
            return conectado;
         }
    }
}
```

Claro, todo esto pensando que tienes alguna aplicación web  wcf, o un ws como tal, pero si no es el caso no es mas facil que :

```
public class MiClase
{
    public static string Db = "server=127.0.10.31;database=Example;UID=admin;PWD=123456"
    public static bool Conectar()
    {
        bool conectado = false;
        SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(Db);
        try
        {            
           conexion.Open();
           conectado = true;
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
           errorconexion = ex.Message;
        }
        return conectado;
     }
}
```

Comment: Tener cuidado con la variable `Db` debería ser `static` quizá , para poder acceder desde el método `static` a su valor.

Comment: @Dev.Joel gracias por el alcance!, voy a modificar

Answer (score 3):

Si tienes un método que `inicializa` tu variable cadena de `Conexion` , deberías llamarlo antes de realizar `SqlConnection` si no, dicha variable no tendrá valor

```
 public static void inicializar() {
  cadenaConexion = "SERVER=127.0.10.31;DATABASE=Example;User id=admin; Password=123456;" 
  } 

 public static  bool Conectar()
    {
        bool conectado = false;
        inicializar(); /*Dar valores a tu cadena de conexion*/
        conexion = new SqlConnection(cadenaConexion);
        try
        {
            conexion.Open();
            conectado = true;
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            errorconexion = ex.Message;
        }
        return conectado;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Te recomiendo que uses un SqlConnectionStringBuilder:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder =
        new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectString);

    // Supply the additional values.
    builder.DataSource = dataSource;
    builder.UserID = userName;
    builder.Password = userPassword;
    Console.WriteLine(builder.ConnectionString);
```

Usa la cadena que te dé con los datos correctos porque tienes un error de formato, creo que es en User id.

Puedes ver la documentación que necesitas el [sitio Developer Network](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: pero la variable `connectString` debe estar inicializada.

Comment: No hace falta, existe el constructor SqlConnectionStringBuilder(). Luego se va añadiendo cada parámetro para formar la cadena.

Comment: Gracias por el dato, no estaba familiarizado con esta clase.